# Assign model to CActiveForm permanently

Tags: yii

It is possible to assign model to be able to render any inputs without `$model` attribute on each field create?

Something like:

```
 $form = $this->beginWidget( 'CActiveForm', array( 'model' => new Model , ... ) );
 $form->textField('onlyAttributeHere');
```

??
Thanks

Comment: as of now it's not possible, check my answer below, btw, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of yii 1.1.10 it's not possible.

You can however extend the [CActiveForm class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm), and add a new variable for this, but you will also have to change all the other methods(mainly html helpers) in that class, to use the new variable as the model.

Comment: @abuduba care to give some feedback? are you not satisfied with this answer?